# Multiple domains with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I have an application that has to shorten URLs, but also do other things. (like `google.com` and `goo.gl`, or `facebook.com` and `fb.me`).

It will be easy to simply deploy two applications, but (for now) it's simpler to be just one. Using spring and spring-mvc. I have the following mappings:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{shortUrlKey}", headers="Host=foo.br")
...
@RequestMapping(value="/{username}")
```

Alas, the `headers` annotation acts not as giving more specific information, but as restricting instead. So if I have these two, only the latter is invoked, even if I open it as `http://foo.br/asdf`. If leave only the former, it works for those coming from `foo.br`, and doesn't open anything if the host is different.

So, the questions:

- how can I make two handlers for the same paths, but different URLs / Hosts
- is it possible to resolve the host dynamically, with a property placeholder configurer (rather than hard-code it in the annotation)

Perhaps both would work if there is some pluggable mechanism for method resolution. Is there such?

Comment: [Managing multiple Domain and Sub Domain](http://technology.sravi.com/2011/05/managing-multiple-domain-and-sub-domain.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My immediate suggestion would be to write a servlet filter (or a Spring `HandlerInterceptor`), which would take the host name from the request, prepend it to the original requested path, then forward on the request.

For example, given the requested URL http://goo.gl/my/path, the filter would forward to `/goo.gl/my/path`. The Spring MVC mappings would then have something to get their teeth into. The ant-style wildcard syntax (e.g. `"**/my/path"`) or path-variable style (e.g. `"{requestHost}/my/path"` might be helpful there.

Alternatively, the filter could set a custom header or request attribute containing the requested host, but that's probably less flexible.

I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your question, though.

Here's a working snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    if (request.getRequestURL().toString().contains(shortenerDomain)
            && !request.getRequestURI().startsWith(SHORT_URI_PREFIX)) {

        request.getRequestDispatcher(SHORT_URI_PREFIX + request.getRequestURI())
                .forward(request, response);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: very good idea :) the 2nd question was about configuring the short hostname rather than hardcoding it. But your suggestion fixes that as well (I'll inject a `@Value` in the interceptor). Will give it a try, and then accept the answer

Comment: works :) added a code snippet. (It could use getHeader("Host"), but it doesn't make a difference)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, it sounds like you could have two controller methods with each domain header mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{shortUrlKey}", headers="Host=foo.br")
public void fooBr() { ... }

@RequestMapping(value="/{shortUrlKey}", headers="Host=bar.bz")
public void barBz() { ... }
```

Comment: I thought of that, yes, and it would probably work (hence +1), but this would mean hardcoding my hosts, which is not that good :)

Comment: spring mvc support placeholders in request mapping annotation, this can work on headers property too