# How to select an http resource through a subdomain?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm developing a spring boot, angularjs app, and my clients will redirect their domains to my system through a cname record, given the nature of a cname record it can't point to an url with a resource (www.myapp.com/clientid), instead i'm trying to select the client through a subdomain (clientid.myapp.com) which can be used by a cname record, i know that this can be done with a http server (nginx) but i want to solve this within the spring boot jar, any ideas?

Comment: Part 1: DNS. Part 2: Map all subdomains to one application. Part 3: Use a Request filter to examine the "Host" header. Part 4: Redirect to a canonical spring URL format (or use include).

Comment: Depends a lot on how you want to have it. E.g. multiple methods http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579743/995891 or just one http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-requestheader-example/ that switches internally

Comment: @zapl does this works behind a CNAME?

Comment: @danillosl You do have to use their domain as host filter. CNAMEs are resolved by DNS directly to some IP, the browser that puts the `Host: yoursite.com` header takes whatever the user enters as URL. http://serverfault.com/questions/147853/cname-how-will-the-url-be-in-the-http-request/147854